# How to create a php array for a month to display an image

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, bin

My dad wrote this code for me a long time ago. The code lives on my computer and then fetches an online image based on the holiday and inserts it into my HTML email signature. If there is no specific holiday, it defaults to the image for the season. I can figure out specific days to be added. But, I don't understand how to add an entry for an entire month.

If I wanted to say make a Black History month that lasted an entire month, how would I do that?

Thanks for any help. There are probably better ways to do this now, but I feel kinda sentimental about this code.

Thanks for any direction.

(:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q

<?php

// Modified March 25, 2017 
// This function return the season as text

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $unixTimeStamp = time();
    $jd = date('z',$unixTimeStamp); 
    if ($jd == 0) $jd =1;
    
    $current_year = date('Y',$unixTimeStamp);
    
    //setup array with the day of November for Thanksgiving starting in 2017
    // additional years can be added after 2035. 
    // similar setup for equinox and solstice below
    // Information for dates can be found in www.timeanddate.com
    
    $thanksgiving_day = array(2017 => 24,23,22,28,26,25,24,23,28,27,26,25,23,22,28,27,25,24,23,22); // good til 2035
    
    $independence_day = array(2017 => 4,4,4,3,4,5,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4);  // good til 2035
    
    $vernal_equinox_date =  array(2017 => 20,20,20,19,20,20,20,19,20,20,20,19,20,20,20,19,20,20,20); // good til 2035
    
    $summer_solstice_date = array(2017 => 20,21,21,20,20,21,21,20,20,20,21,20,20,21,21,20,20,21,21); // good til 2035
    
    $autumal_equinox_date = array(2017 => 22,22,23,22,22,22,23,22,22,22,23,22,22,22,23,22,22,22,23); // good til 2035

    $veterans_day =         array(2017 => 10,12,11,11,11,11,10,11,11,11,11,10,12,11,11,11,11,10,12);  // good til 2035
    
    $winter_solstice_date = 21; // does not change until 2044
    
    $easter_day =   array(2017 => 16,1,21,12,4,17,9,31,20,5,28,16,1,21,13,28,17,9,25); //good through 2035. Date information from Wikipedia
    $easter_month = array(2017 => 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,34,4,3); //good through 2035
     

    // find the day of the year for each special holiday
    // notice: mktime(0,0,0,month, day, year)
    // I may be able to calculate holidays such as Thanksgiving,
    // but holidays such as halloween are easy. Just follow the schema
    // below.
    // then add a new case statement above the top case statement.
    // use christmas for the example.
    
    // See Christmas line: 
    // case $jd >= $christmas - 3 && $jd <= $christmas + 3:
    // From 3 days before christmas until 3 days after christmas. 
    // What is actually says is if today is less than christmas minus 3 
    // and greater than christmas plus 3.
    
    // PERMISSIONS: These will probably need to be changed if you replace the script:
    // Open terminal and type cd ~/bin
    // Type: chmod 777 _seasons.php
    
    $valentines = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,2,14,$current_year));
    $spring = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,3,$vernal_equinox_date[$current_year],$current_year));
    $easter = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,$easter_month[$current_year],$easter_day[$current_year],$current_year));
    $summer = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,6,$vernal_equinox_date[$current_year],$current_year));
    $independenceday = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,7,$independence_day[$current_year], $current_year));
    $fall = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,9,$autumal_equinox_date[$current_year],$current_year));
    $navyday = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,10,13,$current_year));
    $halloween = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,10,31,$current_year));
    $veteransday = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,11, $veterans_day[$current_year], $current_year));
    $thanksgiving = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,11,$thanksgiving_day[$current_year],$current_year));
    $winter = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,12,21,$current_year));
    $christmas = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,12,25,$current_year));
    $newyears = date('z', mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$current_year));


    switch ($jd) {
    
    case $jd >= $christmas - 14 && $jd <= $christmas + 3:
        $sp = "christmas";
        break;
    case $jd >= $newyears && $jd <= $newyears + 5:
        $sp = "newyears";
        break;  
    case $jd >= $halloween - 7 && $jd <= $halloween + 0:
        $sp = "halloween";
        break;
    case $jd == $veteransday:
        $sp = "veteransday";
        break;
    case $jd >= $thanksgiving - 5 && $jd <= $thanksgiving + 0:
        $sp = "thanksgiving";
        break;
    case $jd == $navyday:
        $sp = "navyday";
        break;
    case $jd == $independenceday:
        $sp = "independenceday";
        break;
    case $jd == $valentines:
        $sp = "valentines";
        break;  
    case $jd >= $easter - 5 && $jd <= $easter + 0:
        $sp = "easter";
        break;
    case $jd < $spring || $jd >= $winter:
        $sp = "winter";
        break;
    case $jd < $summer:
        $sp = "spring";
        break;
    case $jd < $fall:
        $sp = "summer";
        break;
    case $jd < $winter:
        $sp = "fall";
        break;

    }
    
    
    echo "<img src=\"http://www.website.com/stamps/Web-Logo-stamp-$sp.jpg\" alt=\"Web Site Title\" width=\"162\" height=\"125\" border=\"0\" style=\"float: left; padding: 0px 16px 0 0;\">";



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the start of Black History Month:

```
$blackhistory = date('z', mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, $current_year));
```

and in your switch statement:

```
case $jd >= $blackhistory && $jd <= $blackhistory + 28 + date('L'):
    $sp = "blackhistory";
    break;
```

February is *normally* 28 days, `date('L')` is `1` when it's a leap year, so adding it will correct for leap years.

Comment: (That said, date logic is a lot easier with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), and you might consider a PHP package for holidays, like https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi.)

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. I didn't even think of leap year. You are smarter than me. Your instructions allowed me to figure out how to do it if it were a normal month. THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

I'll check out the Carbon package you mentioned.